# Xcode UI Test doesn't get start running

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I cannot start running my UITest. It throws falling errors.

```
The bundle "MyUITests" couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.

(dlopen_preflight(/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CTSS-bitrvpnmpmabyhcckpiqoinipvcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyUITests.xctest/MyUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/AFDateHelper.framework/AFDateHelper
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-bitrvpnmpmabyhcckpiqoinipvcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyUITests.xctest/MyUITests
  Reason: image not found)
```